# Прямая от первого объекта до второго

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {

  $("#Point1").draggable();
  //$("#Point2").draggable();



});
```

```css
#Point1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
}
#Point2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 90px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
  -moz-border-radius: 19px;
}
#line1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="Point1">
  <div id="line1">
    <div id="Point2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

хотелось чтобы визуально была видная прямая от объекта1 до объекта2, т.е. объект 1 не перетаскивается, объект2 беру мышку и таскаю по рабочей области и от одного объекта до другого протягивается прямая линия.Можно ли реализовать с помощью jquery?

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону canvas, или каких-то JavaScript библиотек, ориентированных на работу с графикой. На дивах, вам не удастся построить линии под произвольным углом из одной точки в другую. (Вернее, это теоретически возможно, но жутко костыльно, неочевидно и ненадежно.)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, как рисовать линии на CSS3: http://www.monkeyandcrow.com/blog/drawing_lines_with_css3/

```
div.line{
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  height: 3px; /* Line width of 3 */
  background: #000; /* Black fill */
}

function createLine(x1,y1, x2,y2){
    var length = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
  var angle  = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
  var transform = 'rotate('+angle+'deg)';

    var line = $('<div>')
        .appendTo('#page')
        .addClass('line')
        .css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'transform': transform
        })
        .width(length)
        .offset({left: x1, top: y1});

    return line;
}
```

Надо иметь ввиду, что это решение не будет кроссбраузерным.

Если вы добавите canvas в свой проект, [здесь](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp) смотрите пример как пользоваться `lineTo`.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот набросал функцию рисующая дивом линию между блоками.

**(Внимание - в конце ответа есть обновление функции "addLine" с кроссбраузерностью и jQuery)**

```js
// Собственно сама функция добавления линии
function addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, container) {
  var len = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)),
    angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) / Math.PI * 180;
  angle = (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.left = x1 + 'px';
  div.style.top = y1 + 'px';
  div.style.background = 'black';
  div.style.width = len + 'px';
  div.style.height = '1px';

  div.style.transformOrigin = '0% 0%';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
  container.appendChild(div);
}

// ---- Остальной код ----
var box1 = $('#box1'),
  box2 = $('#box2'),
  offset1 = box1.offset(),
  offset2 = box2.offset(),
  box1WC = box1.width() / 2,
  box1HC = box1.height() / 2,
  box2WC = box2.width() / 2,
  box2HC = box2.height() / 2;

addLine(offset1.left + box1WC, offset1.top + box1HC,
  offset2.left + box2WC, offset2.top + box2HC,
  document.body);
```

```css
.box {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
#box1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
#box2 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
```

### Обновление

Переписал функцию, чтобы работало с jQuery и со всеми браузерами:

```
function addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, container) {
  var len = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)),
    angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) / Math.PI * 180;
  angle = (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;

  var div = $('<div/>').css({
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'left' : x1,
    'top' : y1,
    'background' : 'black',
    'width' : len,
    'height' : '1px',

    '-webkit-transform-origin'  : '0% 0%',
    '-moz-transform-origin'     : '0% 0%',
    '-ms-transform-origin'      : '0% 0%',
    '-o-transform-origin'       : '0% 0%',
    'transform-origin'          : '0% 0%',

    '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform'    : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform'     : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform'      : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
    'transform'         : 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
  });


  div.appendTo(container);
}
```